# AMPscript ELSEIF statement evaluating incorrectly

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have an ELSEIF AMPscript statement that looks like this:

```html
<script runat=server language=ampscript>

var @code, @templateName

set @code = 'M200'

if @code == 'E001' then
   set @templateName = 'Letter A'
elseif @code == 'M001'
     or @code == 'M014'
     or @code == 'M400' then
   set @templateName = 'Letter B'
elseif @code == 'M002'
     or @code == 'M500' then
   set @templateName = 'Letter C'
elseif @code == 'M003' 
     or @code == 'M200' then
   set @templateName = 'Letter D'
elseif  @code == 'M004'
     or @code == 'M005'
     or @code == 'M006'
     or @code == 'M007'
     or @code == 'M008'
     or @code == 'M009'
     or @code == 'M010'
     or @code == 'M011'
     or @code == 'M012'
     or @code == 'M013'
     or @code == 'M600' then
    set @templateName = 'Letter E'
elseif @code == 'M015' then
   set @templateName = 'Letter F'
elseif @code == 'V100' then
   set @templateName ='Letter G'
else
   set @templateName = 'undefined'
endif
</script>

%%=v(@templateName)=%%
```

I would expect `@templateName` to return 'Letter D' but it is returning 'Letter E'. Why do you think this is?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Is it in an email?

Comment: My first thought was it block definition -- `<script runat=server language=ampscript><script>` -- since it is processed differently than the traditional `%%[ ]%% `.  That's the way I understand it.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs if you copy and paste the example above into an email you will be able to reproduce. However you are correct; if I use `%%[ ]%%` in my email, then it works. I thought the [tag based syntax](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_function_calls/) could be used interchangeably — I had no idea that they are evaluated differently!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. I used two space characters after one of my `elseif` statements for formatting (alignment) purposes:

```
elseif  @code == 'M004'
```

If you do this, it appears that the if statement evaluation breaks and returns the incorrect result. As soon as I remove the second space character, it works correctly:

```
elseif @code == 'M004'
```

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy and this solution not something I had even considered as being able to cause the error.